# How to fill text with image

Tags: imagemagick

How can I create such an image using imagemagick:

[image]
[image]

That is, text on top of a solid-color background. The text's fill is not solid color but actually an image, as if the image is the background and the shape of the text has been cut out of the foreground solid fill.

I hope imagemagick has the capability to take as input at least

- the background image
- font to use
- solid color to fill the rest with

and output an image like above.

Does anyone know how I can do so?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

With some bits borrowed from an answer [here](https://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=14839) and the imagemagick docs...

Creating the example text-background and image-background (any image would work, using solid colors here as a proof of concept):

```bsh
convert -size 500x100 xc:dodgerblue -gravity center -background gold -extent 500x300 text_bg.png
convert -size 500x300 xc:red image_bg.png
```

[image: text_bg][image: image_bg]

Creating a text mask (black text on transparent background):

```bsh
convert -background none -font /usr/share/fonts/TTF/TerminusTTF-Bold.ttf -pointsize 60\
-fill black label:'Test Mask Text' -rotate 25 -gravity center -extent 500x300 text.png
```

[image: text.png]

And now to composite the three:

```bsh
convert image_bg.png text_bg.png text.png -composite comp.png
```

[image: comp.png]

Comment: Which ImageMagick version/s did you use for this?  When I try with 6.8.9-9 (and include the missing filename in the first step), the end result is solid red; I need to set the text background to white (rather than `none`/transparent) for it to work as a mask in the `composite` step.

Comment: @JigglyNaga Interesting, and thanks for pointing out the missing filename.  I'm on `Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-13`